# How do I get main.dart.testing page back? I think that's what it was called?

Tags: flutter, dart, testing

At first my problem was that MyApp isn't defined and then I deleted the page that was for testing(?)... Now my problem is - A build function returned null. Offending widget is MyApp.
How do I get that page back? Do you have the code for it?

Here's the code I'm trying to run on an ios simulator, it's not right but it used to be white, now it has a red screen with that text

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Color(0x50658C), Color(0x2D4067)],
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm very new at this

Comment: What are your trying to do? Describe step by step

Comment: I updated my question, is that helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens because you missed a `return`. In your case you forgot to return the `MaterialApp`.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Missing return
    return MaterialApp(
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Write below code in `main.dart`:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final appTitle = 'Drawer Demo';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(title: appTitle, theme: ThemeData.light(),
         home: LoginScreen(), // Do not specify Home when specifying routes.
       );
  }
}

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Text('Done'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And run project....